# How to publish Mobile First buid code in web sphere without eclipse

Tags: eclipse, websphere, mobilefirst-server, mobilefirst-cli, mobilefirst-studio

I am new to Mobile First apps creation and publishing part in web sphere. I could like to know

1. how to publish build code in eclipse(which is in my local system) to
   web sphere in server
2. What are the minimum required software's that are required in server to publish
3. Is it possible to publish code in server
   without eclipse in server, If so can I know how to do that.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> how to publish build code in eclipse(which is in my local system) to web sphere in server

Read the documentation: http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/install_config/c_wlserver_plan_install.html?lang=en

The build in the MobileFirst development environment in Eclipse generates .wlapp, .adapter and .war files. You need to setup a production environment (must be a licensed customer of IBM) and then follow the instructions in the guide above in order to first deploy the the server artifacts -> the .war file -> and then the .wlapp and .adapter files.

> What are the minimum required software's that are required in server to publish

See the Prerequisites website: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27024838#IMF_71

> Is it possible to publish code in server without eclipse in server, If so can I know how to do that.

You must first build the required artifacts. This must be done using either MobileFirst Studio or MobileFirst CLI.

Comment: Thanks @Idan Adar, I will go through the links.